# How to parse interfaces with GSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I've have an interface model with nested interfaces.
For each interface there is also mainly 1 concrete implementation class like:

```
public interface Book {

    String getTitle();
}

public class BookImpl implements Book {

    private String title;

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Now to parse the json like:

```
gson.fromJson(json, Book.class);
```

Does not work as it does not know the implementation class.

So I created a custom deserializer like:

```
public class BookDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Book> {

    @Override
    public Book deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return context.deserialize(json, BookImpl.class);
    }
}
```

But I do this for each interface in my model.

Is that the proper way to this? Creating such a simplistic deserializer? I feel there should be an easier way.

Like with Jackson I would create a custom Jackson `Module` and register the type mapping like:

```
.addAbstractTypeMapping(Book.class, BookImpl.class)
```

Is this also possible with GSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic version of `JsonDeserializer`

```
public static class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer {
    private Class<?> implClass;

    public MyDeserializer(Class<?> c) {
        implClass = c;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return context.deserialize(json, implClass);
    }
}
```

And register it pretty much like in Jackson with one line

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new MyDeserializer(AImpl.class));
builder.registerTypeAdapter(B.class, new MyDeserializer(BImpl.class));
```

---

Or just use lambda like

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(G.class, (JsonDeserializer) (json, typeOfT, context)
                -> context.deserialize(json, H.class));
```

Comment: Yes a custom generic deserializer is a good option. I'm only wondering why there is nothing like that available already. That is why I was thinking I'm overlooking something.

Comment: @MarcelOverdijk actually in my experience it is pretty common. Jackson is much more complex and feature rich framework. Here is [nice list](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-better-Jackson-or-Gson/answer/Hima-Sekhar-Reddy)  But in this case it looks to me that jackson `addAbstractTypeMapping` is just a syntax sugar for `addDeserializer/addSerializer`. It is just lazy version of       `builder.registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new Gson().getAdapter(AImpl.class));`. And i actually think that gson has cooler  feature `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter` to setup single adapter for every implementation

Comment: OK thx, I will ook at the `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter` as well.